# Replace all in JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i have below string from which I have to extract username and ID.

```
This is a string which has a @[User Full Name](contact:1)  data inside.
```

To get username and contact id from above string I am using this regex pattern.

```
    var re = /\@\[(.*)\]\(contact\:(\d+)\)/;
    text = text.replace(re,"username:$1 with ID: $2");
// result == username: User Full Name with ID: 1
```

It works perfectly now issue is I have multiple usernames in string, I tried using /g (global) but its not replacing properly:
Example string:

```
This is a string which has a @[User Full Name](contact:1)  data inside. and it can also contain many other users data like  @[Second Username](contact:2) and  @[Third username](contact:3) and so many others....
```

when used global I get this result:

```
var re = /\@\[(.*)\]\(contact\:(\d+)\)/g;
text = text.replace(re,"username:$1 with ID: $2");
//RESULT from above     
This is a string which has a user username; User Full Name](contact:1) data inside. and it can also contain many other users data like @[[Second Username](contact:2) and @[Third username and ID: 52 and so many others....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a non greedy `?` match in your first capture group. By having `.*` you are matching the most amount possible  while if you use `.*?`, it matches the least amount possible.

```
/@\[(.*?)\]\(contact:(\d+)\)/
```

And if the word *contact* is not always there, you could do..

```
/@\[(.*?)\]\([^:]+:(\d+)\)/
```

See [working demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/jI5yC6)

Comment: Why are you escaping `@`?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I can see how your resulting string is going to be usable. How about something like this...

```
var re = /@\[(.*?)\]\(contact:(\d+)\)/g;
var users = [];
var match = re.exec(text);
while (match !== null) {
    users.push({
        username: match[1],
        id: match[2]
    });
    match = re.exec(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Phil... informative but actually I am parsing that string data from database to view for user so there is no use of it at this point.... :) Thanks again.